# How can we read Lossless compressed JPEG images

Tags: java, image, image-processing, lossless-compression

I have some medical images and that was compressed as lossless images.
These images can read only in matlab and accusoft Java API.

How we can load these type of images in java?

My current code is:

```
Image img = null;
ImageInputStream iis = new FileImageInputStream(file);

for (Iterator<ImageReader> i = ImageIO.getImageReaders(iis);
                        img == null && i.hasNext();) {
    ImageReader r = i.next();
    try {
        r.setInput(iis);
        img = r.read(0);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

System.out.println("Imagee  : "+img);
```

But i am getting the exception :

```
javax.imageio.IIOException: Unsupported JPEG process: SOF type 0xc3
    at 
com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readImageHeader(Native Method)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readNativeHeader(JPEGImageReader.java:609)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.checkTablesOnly(JPEGImageReader.java:347)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.gotoImage(JPEGImageReader.java:481)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readHeader(JPEGImageReader.java:602)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readInternal(JPEGImageReader.java:1059)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.read(JPEGImageReader.java:1039)
    at javax.imageio.ImageReader.read(ImageReader.java:939)
    at losslessimagereader.LosslessImageReader.main(LosslessImageReader.java:49)
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: @LijoJoseph I'm working on a project to add JPEG Lossless support to ImageIO, but it will take some time before it's ready. I guess your best bet at the moment is using JAI.

Comment: I removed the Matlab tag as this question seems to relate to Java (I don't think that Matlab's ability to open a file format makes a tag appropriate). Feel free edit your question and make the connection to Matlab more explicit if there are other details.